# OfBiz Installation Failure

Tags: ant, ofbiz

Apache OfBiz is not installing correctly, and fails to compile in the command prompt.

After creating the system variable JAVA_HOME to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40, and editing "Path" to be C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin;C:\apache-ant-1.9.4\bin, I downloaded OfBiz 13.07.01 to my C:\ folder and unzipped it there. In the command prompt, I typed the following:

```
C:\Users\CalS>cd C:\apache-ofbiz-13.07.01
C:\apache-ofbiz-13.07.01>ant load-seed
```

Then, after about 50 seconds, I get this:

```
BUILD FAILED
C:\apache-ofbiz-13.07.01\build.xml:229: the following error occurred while executing this line: 
C:\apache-ofbiz-13.07.01\build.xml:248: the following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\apache-ofbiz-13.07.01\build.xml:39: the following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\apache-ofbiz-13.07.01\build.xml:91: compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

Please note it has been years since I dealt with DOS, so I do not know how to access the error output.

This is after I get a few dozen errors like:
    [javac16] class file for org.ofbiz.widget.ContentWorkerInterfaice not found

and

```
[javac16] warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunctions with -source 1.6
```

Under 'classes'.

Misc. I have tried 'ant run-install' and 'load-demo' commands without avail. I've followed step-by-step tutorials, but very likely missed something. Please let me know what I can do to fix this and run this program successfully. Thanks!

Comment: Please make sure you compile/run with the same Java version. Seems you have some inconsistencies: JAVA_HOME ist 1.8, Path is set to jre 7 and the warning states it is using an 1.6 compiler.

Comment: @MichaelBrohl Ok. I fixed that, and java 1.8.xx is installed now, thank you for pointing that out. However, Apache ant 13.07.01 keeps trying to compile off of -version 1.6. How do I get it to compile off of 1.8.xx?

Comment: I have made an answer out of my comment, seems to be the right one ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so it looks like Apache OFBiz and Java JDK 1.8.XX don't get along. I found help on another forum that confirmed the discrepancy in compatibility between OFBiz 13.07.01/Apache ant 1.9.4 and JDK 1.8.XX. This will cause the compiling of the Apache Ant to fail (which seems to run off of JDK 1.6).

I remedied the problem by downloading the archived JDK 1.7.0_67 from Oracle, re-mapping the System Variables accordingly, and re-initializing the Command Prompt.

It works now! Thank you all for your contributions.

Answer (score 3):

Please have a look at the following Apache Jira Tickets for OFBiz where your problem is addressed and was fixed, so that OFBiz could be build with java 1.8.

The build errors occur due to missing fileset entries in the build.xml for some applications (party, workeffort, product, order, ebay, and pos), see: [OFBIZ-5835](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OFBIZ-5835)

A fix is available in related ticket: [OFBIZ-6079](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OFBIZ-6079)

There was another bug in the current release branches (checked 14.12.01, 12.04.06, 13.07.02) that I fixed last week. The fix is already committed to the branches.

See: [OFBIZ-6252](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OFBIZ-6252)

Answer (score 0):

You have to compile/run with the same Java version.

Seems you have some inconsistencies: JAVA_HOME ist 1.8, Path is set to jre 7 and the warning states it is using an 1.6 compiler.

With the 13.07. Release, using Java 1.7 or 1.8 is recommended and supported.

Comment: Ok. So the paths are now: JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20
Path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_40\bin;C:\Users\Public\Dev\Apps\apache-ant-1.9.4\bin using the latest versions of JRE and JDK. However, it still fails to build, and seems to want to use version 1.6. How do I bridge the gap and tell it to compile off of 1.8?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know how to get to the compiler error output from Command Prompt. Could you tell me so I could access that for you? I just wiped everything and started over from scratch, only to get the same results... 

I have to believe there's an easier way to go about this.

Answer (score 0):

Though solved, let me add something important. JDK version is not always an issue in such errors. Ofbiz v13.X.X works well on JDK 1.7 and above. The error shown is a peculiar issue with Ofbiz v13.07.01 dist.

As Martin pointed out, one need to add widget jars in the classpath of `order`, `party`, `product` & `workeffort`. Add the below line

```
<fileset dir="../../framework/widget/build/lib" includes="*.jar"/>
```

in build.xml of `order`, `party`, `product` & `workeffort` under `applications` directory.